# iOS: NTLM auth before using SharePoint Server

Tags: ios, sharepoint, soap, ntlm

How would I get authenticated on SharePoint via NTLM (Windows Based), before I send SOAP requests to web-services?
Should I get a token via ASIHTTPRequest or CFNetwork?
Example code would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a connection Challenged part to connection urls that i called when a connection is challenged or authentication...

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.userName
                                                         password:self.userPassword
                                                         persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] ;
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"Getting Authentication Challenges");

}
```

Not sure where I found it (and thanks to whoever it was!) but this works for me. But in all honesty I'm not using soap requests and I'm not suing any connection libs....

Hope this is some help.

Comment: Does it send my password encrypted after I put it in NSURLCredential?

Comment: I think its when it's requested by the connection.... 

(But I'm just learning this as well....)